# Pass object into method and determine type

Tags: c#

I'm not sure the best way to ask this question, but I would like to pass an object into a method and depending on the type of object use that object through the function. There may be another solution so let me explain the situation.

I have a customer returning two objects (Foo and Bar) to me. However, those objects are nearly identical so I'm trying to write one function to read the data.

Here is a code snippet of what I would like to do but this obviously wont work.

```
        public static void MyFunction(object obj)
        {

            object order = null;
            if (typeof(Foo) == obj.GetType())
            {
                order = obj as Foo;
            }
            else
                order = obj as Bar;

            // get data from order

        }
```

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _"those objects are nearly identical"_ - use an interface.

Comment: Are you able to change the objects Foo and Bar? If they are similar enough you could make them both implement an interface and then type your parameter to that interface. Otherwise if you can't have an interface I'd go with two overloads, one for each. They might have very similar code but the other options for sharing code are a bit messy and fragile (at least the ones I am thinking of).

Comment: Foo and Bar are coming from their web service that I don't have access to. Chris -- you're probably right about creating the overload...That's most likely the best option for future changes.

Comment: `object order = obj as TypeName` is not terribly useful: because both `order` and `obj` are typed as `object`, you won't be able to do anything type-specific with `order` without even more casting. `Foo foo = obj as Foo; if (foo != null) ...` will give you a `Foo` object you can work with, or `null` if `obj` wasn't a `Foo`. You can also use the `is` operator: `if (obj is Foo) { Foo foo = (Foo)obj; ... }`.

Comment: You could use a dynamic object: `var dynObj = (dynamic)obj;` You should then be able to access properties common to Foo and Bar without compile time type checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect there's a lot more to your scenario that we as a community could comment on, such as the use of an interface as mentioned in the comments.  But, knowing only what we know, you could try something simple, like this:

```
    public static void MyFunction(object obj)
    {
        Foo foo;
        Bar bar;

        if ((foo = obj as Foo) != null)
             //Work with foo here.
        else if ((bar = obj as Bar) != null)
             //Work with bar here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to have a common interface to `Foo` and `Bar` and you can't make them share a base class or implement an interface (maybe they're in an assembly you don't own), you can use the adapter pattern.

You could make an abstract base class that defines all the properties you need to access, then derive from that base class once for each object you need to manipulate. Then you just create the right adapter for the type of object you have, passing in the object the adapter needs to adapt, and store it to a reference of the base class type to use later.

You can do the same with an interface instead of an abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options basically and they both require you to have some element of commonality such as a common base class or interface declaration... for the example below I've used an interface:

```
public interface IFooBar 
{
    ...
}

// Option 1: Just type the parameter to the interface (the simplest)
public static void MyFunction(IFooBar obj)
{
    // get data from order
}

// Option 2: Use a generic type parameter and constraint that it must 
// be of type IFooBar (this can be useful for certain reflection scenarios)
public static void MyFuntion<TObject>(TObject obj)
    where TObject: IFooBar
{
    // get data from order
}

// Option 2a: Same as Option 2 however we take advantage of the constraint 
// to inform the the compiler that TObject will have a default parameterless
// constructor so we can actually instantiate TObject
public static void MyFuntion<TObject>(TObject obj)
    where TObject: IFooBar, new()
{
    // get data from order
    ...

    // We can do this because of the new() constraint
    return new TObject();
}
```